# Using .htaccess mod_rewrite to bypass a deep directory structure to CSS assets

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a setup like so

> http://localhost/
>   http://localhost/ci_tada/
>   http://localhost/ci_tada/application
>   http://localhost/ci_tada/application/views
>   http://localhost/ci_tada/application/views/css
>   http://localhost/ci_tada/application/views/css/master.css

I dont want to have to write

> http://localhost/ci_tada/application/views/css/

every time i wish to access a css file (the same will apply for images ect)

I want to be able to just use
http://localhost/ci_tada/css/master.css

and have it load the correct file.

The .htaccess file is located in the ci_tada folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're using some sort of routes within a framework. You should check, because some frameworks give you the option to do it in the app configuration.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# directory base, untogle if you want to
# rewrite only starting from /<directory/path>
# RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/css/(.*)$ index.php/ci_tada/application/views/css/$1 [PT,L]
#or RewriteRule ^/(.*)/css(.*)$ index.php/$0/views/css$1 [PT,L]
#or RewriteRule ^/(.*)/css/(.*)$ index.php/$0/views/css/$1 [PT,L]

</IfModule>
```

Beware that the last two redirect everything that contains /css/ in the path.

---

edit:1: It is considered best practice in CI (from what I've read), to set a static directory on your root like this:

```
    /
    .../static
    ......./css
    ......./js
    .../application
    ......./controller
    .../...
```

So that you can simply use /static/css/file.css inline in your views. Also see these resources if they can help:

- http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/60563/#297784

Comment: Ah I did not even think about the routing. Any idea about how I could do the routing in code Igniter as, as far as I am aware, the routing still goes through the index.php

Comment: Can you show us your .htaccess, so I can integrate it with the answer above. Also see this SO thread if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729340/how-do-i-add-some-static-routes-to-a-codeigniter-app

Comment: I ended up using your second approach by moving my assets folder to the root.

Answer (score 0):

I feel you are talking about Zend Framework.  Your few lines are

/

/application

How can every request can be redirected to CSS/? Then your application will not work!

In Zend Framework, application/layouts/scripts/layout.phtml, you mention css file like this:

```
<?php echo $this->headLink()->prependStylesheet($this->baseUrl().'/css/site.css'); ?>
```

Css file go in project folder. It is outside application folder:
\quickstart2\public\css.

*Hope I will not receive -ve answer.*

Comment: ok, ZF has that facility. Code Igniter should also have like that. If you fix your code when developing then at later stage you can in trouble!